# Can't replace pixel value in the destination image after homography

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement warpperspective function from opencv manually.

My interpretation of the warpperspective is this :

1. Apply homography to every `[x,y,1]` in the source image to get `[x'/a y'/a a]`
2. For every `[x'/a y'/a]` coordinate in the destination image, replace the pixel value (intensity) by the pixel value of `[x y]` coordinate in the source image.

But I am getting too large `x'/a y'/a` values which are out of bounds for the `background`

I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('cola.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
background = cv2.imread('stadium.jpg')
background = cv2.cvtColor(background,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

row,col,ch=img.shape
print(row)
print(col)
print(ch)
print("bbb",img[0,0,0])

rows_p,cols_p,ch_p = background.shape
print(rows_p)
print(cols_p)
print(ch_p)

pts1 = np.float32([[0,0],[974,0],[0,974],[974,974]]) # cola coords 
pts2 = np.float32([[560,383],[940, 516],[5,527],[298,733]]) # stadium tile coords

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
print(M)

Store_Matrix=np.empty([3,1])
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        Store_Matrix=np.dot(M,img[i,j])
        X=Store_Matrix[0].astype(int)
        Y=Store_Matrix[1].astype(int)
        background[X,Y,1]=img[i,j,1]
        background[X,Y,2]=img[i,j,2]
        background[X,Y,3]=img[i,j,3]  # trying to take the pixel vale from the source image for every channel and replacing the pixel value in the backgroung image (the new coordinates after applying homo)graphy
```

Comment: obviously pixels can be warped out of the destination image. You could either choose a bigger destination image and shift the output (to overcome negative coordinates) or you could ignore/drop all those pixels and just draw the ones which fall into your destination image area. Another important thing is, that for efficiency and coverage, typically you dont effectively warp from source to destination, but inverse warp from destination pixel positions to source pixels, so you can be sure that you have a dense result etc.